# How can I add an augment to my weapon?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I found a nice blueprint for an assault rifle as well as some augments. I researched both, but now I don't see any option to actually apply the augment to the assault rifle.

[image]

From the description in-game I would have expected this to happen in the development phase, but there is no option here to add an augment. I can craft the Valkyrie assault rifle I researched here, and I can see the augments in my inventory, but I can't find any option to select an augment here.

So, how do I apply an augment to my weapon?

Comment: You're correct in your assumption, you would normally apply the augs at the time (or just prior technically) of building the weapon. As to why you were not able, it might be as Espada said, the weapon level is too low.

Comment: yep, not all weapons can accept augments, especially not at rank 1.  I have a rank 2 valkyrie assault rifle with 4 augments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slots for augmentations only appear on higher level versions of items.

Augmentations are added during the development of the item by selecting the augment slots in the same way as you would when adding mods on the load out screen:

[image: augmentations on the development screen]

Answer (score 1):

Most weapon at lvl 2 got augmentation slot. The first lvl for all weapon do not have. You will need to research the second lvl for that rifle.